# Password reset not checking for existing users

Tags: swift, parse-platform

In my password reset function the user can put in whatever he/she wants. It does not even needs to be a email address.

I would like to check for a valid email address, and that the email is registered in Parse Server

```
@IBAction func forgotPasswordButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

let forgotPasswordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Forgot password?", message: "Please enter your email address", preferredStyle: .alert)
forgotPasswordAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
forgotPasswordAlert.addTextField { (textField) in
    textField.placeholder = "Email address"
}
forgotPasswordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
forgotPasswordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset password", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    let resetEmail = forgotPasswordAlert.textFields?.first?.text
    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: resetEmail!, block: { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            let resetFailedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetFailedAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
            resetFailedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetFailedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let resetEmailSentAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Password reset instructions sendt", message: "Please check your email", preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetEmailSentAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
            resetEmailSentAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetEmailSentAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })

}))
//PRESENT ALERT
self.present(forgotPasswordAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your action you can check for email validity:-

```swift
forgotPasswordAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Reset password", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    let resetEmail = forgotPasswordAlert.textFields?.first?.text
if self.isValidEmail(testStr: resetEmail) {
// Check of email registered on server should be done via this API and API should return error based on that.
    PFUser.requestPasswordResetForEmail(inBackground: resetEmail!, block: { (success, error) in
        if error != nil {
            let resetFailedAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetFailedAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
            resetFailedAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetFailedAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let resetEmailSentAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Password reset instructions sendt", message: "Please check your email", preferredStyle: .alert)
            resetEmailSentAlert.view.tintColor = UIColor.red
            resetEmailSentAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(resetEmailSentAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    })
} else {
//Show error that email entered is not correct format
// present the reset email alertbox again.
}

}))

func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {        
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}"

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluate(with: testStr)
}
```

Comment: Accepted this, but it still don't check if the email is registered in the database

Comment: As explained in other answers providing that an email is registered or not create a security issue (Security by obscurity). It's better to just show User a generic message:-
`You will receive an email to reset the password if your email exists (or you are registered)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a parse email adapter to verify emails.

`Verifying user email addresses and enabling password reset via email requires an email adapter. As part of the parse-server package we provide an adapter for sending email through Mailgun. To use it, sign up for Mailgun, and add this to your initialization code:`

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server

Comment: I have Mailgun installed and working. I'm using it to both password reset as in my question above, and to verify email address when signing up. But its not checking for a registered email address when entering email address for password reset.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to Parse Server not notifying the client that a user with the provided email address does not exist:

Pre 3.1.0 of Parse Server the request to reset a password returned an error if the email address was not found however this is a security risk as it allows an attacker to obtain user data for use in a brute force attack - see this [explanation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_(OWASP-AT-002)).

You can also take a look at the [changelog](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) and the [PR that implemented this change](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/5103).

It would still be possible to implement this yourself by querying the `User` class before making the password reset request. However, this should not be done in client code as it would require user data to be publicly accessible which is a major breach of privacy. It could also be implemented in cloud code using the master key so that user data could remain inaccessible to the public but this would present the same security risk mentioned above.